# Sublime Text error "/bin/sh: 1 php not found" in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

in Ubuntu, in Sublime Text 3, every I save the file, I get the error:

```
/bin/sh: 1 php not found
```

So I went there to see:

```
$ ll sh*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    4 déc.   3 13:14 sh -> dash

$ readlink -f sh
/usr/bin/dash

$ ll /usr/bin/da*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 127K juil. 18  2019 /usr/bin/dash
```

Can you help?

Thanks

Comment: The error is about a missing `php` command, *called from* `/bin/sh`, rather than a missing `/bin/sh` command itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're working on php files and have something setup in sublimetext to use php for building

-> install php to solve the issue

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php
```